# Google Spreadsheets Scripting Server Error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have some spreadsheets that use the scripting feature to move, process, and create data in Google Spreadsheets, but recently, when I try to check the Script Manager or Script Editor on one of these, I get a server error.  I also have some code that makes them autoload into a menu option upon opening the spreadsheet, but that of course doesn't work either because the scripts are unavailable as a whole.

It's been this way for at least a week with no change, and I don't really have any idea how to fix it.  The scripts are pretty vital and lengthy, so I don't really want to make them again...

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, it's not just the one sheet I see, but it's not all of them either.

Comment: +1. We found the same error on Google Spreadsheet.

Comment: If you're having this problem, could you post the project key? You can find it under File > Project Properties in the script editor.